# ¿Por que me aparece este error : "WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data"?

Tags: android, android-studio, linux, windows

estoy tratando de compilar mi proyecto android en Windows ya que el desarrollo del mismo fue en Linux pero al intentar correr la aplicación me aparece este mensaje:

> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si a alguien le sucedio algo similar alguna vez.

Comment: 1. Haz un Rebuild de tu proyecto. Si no funciona, 2. **Copia en otra carpeta el archivo** slice6.apk de la carpeta `slices/debug...` indicada en el error  y bórralo de la carpeta original  e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: No esto no es un error **No es un error tipográfico!**, revisen mi respuesta.

Comment: Te está informando que tienes una versión ya instalada en el smartphone

Comment: Webserveis así es, en realidad es solo un "Warning", que no le debe afectar al funcionamiento de la aplicación.

Comment: El problema es que no se instala la aplicación, y no hay aplicación instalada, cuando le doy en "ok" deja de instalar y me manda el error de la imagen  que esta abajo de la primera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En realidad no es un problema que afecte a tu aplicación, lo que sucede es que el .apk que intenta subir a tu dispositivo es diferente versión a la instalada, firmada con un certificado diferente.

Principalmente puede ser una versión firmada para producción que intenta ser reemplazada con una aplicación de desarrollo firmada con el Keystore debug.

> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to unistall the existing application?

Solo selecciona que si y la reemplazará.

---

Este es un ejemplo, tengo una aplicación instalada desde Google Play, firmada con un Keystore especifico para la tienda, pero intento subir a mi dispositivo la misma aplicación (es la misma aplicación cuando tiene el mismo id de paquete), me muestra el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al instalar la aplicación la siguiente ocasión ya no me mostraría el mensaje.
Incluso ocurre si la aplicación se subio en otra pc ya que se "firmo" con otro keystore de debug.