# ¿Porque no puedo ejecutar mi aplicacion en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando intento ejecutar mi aplicacion en mi celular me sale siempre este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya deshabilite el instant run, pero sigue dandome este error, tambien ya desinstale la aplicacion de mi telefono y nada funciona

Comment: En realidad el mensaje se muestra ya que estas tratando de subir un .apk y existe actualmente en el dispositivo una aplicación instalada pero que fue firmada con otro certificado, simplemente da clic en "OK", de esta forma se instalará el .apk que intentas subir, revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60395/por-que-me-aparece-este-error-warning-uninstalling-will-remove-the-applicat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En tu móvil activa la instalación de aplicaciones de orígenes desconocidos, la depuración usb (te recomiendo también que revoques los certificados antes de volver a conectarlo al pc) y elimina los datos y la aplicación desde tu móvil.

Si aún con esto sigue fallando prueba a instalar la primera vez de manera manual el apk. Para generar el apk en el android studio haz click derecho en la carpeta de tu proyecto y selecciona `Android tools` y exportar apk, puedes hacerlo firmada y sin firmar, en tu caso intuyo que aun estás haciendo pruebas por lo que puedes exportarla sin firmar. También puedes buscarla por los directorios de tu proyecto si has conseguido al menos compilar, debería estar bajo el directorio `bin`